# Getting Full User Name Wrong

Tags: username, passwd-file

Why when I issue a command like:

```
awk -F: -v U="$LOGNAME" '$1==U{print $5}' /etc/passwd
```

or

```
grep $USER /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } { print $5 }'
```

is displayed `Diogo Saraiva,,,` instead of `Diogo Saraiva`?

When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 I wrote `Diogo Saraiva`, not `Diogo Saraiva,,,` in Full name field...

---

result of `cat /etc/passwd | grep diogosaraiva`:

```
diogosaraiva:x:1000:1000:Diogo Saraiva,,,:/home/diogosaraiva:/bin/bash
```

Can I change that line for

```
diogosaraiva:x:1000:1000:Diogo Saraiva:/home/diogosaraiva:/bin/bash
```

without any problem?

---

And my user isn't the unique issue.

In /etc/passwd file:

```
...    
diogosaraiva:x:1000:1000:Diogo Saraiva,,,:/home/diogosaraiva:/bin/bash
sshd:x:116:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mysql:x:117:125:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
sysop:x:1001:1001::/home/sysop:/bin/bash
dovecot:x:118:126:Dovecot mail server,,,:/usr/lib/dovecot:/bin/false
dovenull:x:119:127:Dovecot login user,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
postfix:x:120:128::/var/spool/postfix:/bin/false
vmail:x:5000:5000::/var/mail:
...
```

Comment: Try `grep $USER /etc/passwd | awk -F'[,:]' '{print $5}'`

Comment: Quick explanation, in `awk -F'[??]'` allows you to choose multiple field separators.  Field separators are not included in your output.

Comment: Also, `awk -F'[:,]' -v U="$LOGNAME" '$1==U{print $5}' /etc/passwd` works for the first line.  Also, the 3 commas are extra information for that field like phone number, address, etc.  Probably not wise to remove them.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Terrance `awk -F'[:,]' -v U="$LOGNAME" '$1==U{print $5}' /etc/passwd` and `grep $USER /etc/passwd | awk -F'[,:]' '{print $5}'` worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fifth field of `/etc/passwd` is known as the [GECOS field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field), it is reserved for saving user's name and comments. The entries you are seeing solely depends on how you add the user using `adduser` command.

I will give your answer by just showing two examples of `adduser`:

**FIRST CASE:**  Just the `Full Name` is given, No other info:

```
$ sudo adduser foobar
Adding user `foobar' ...
........Truncated.............
passwd: password updated successfully

Changing the user information for foobar
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: foobar foobar
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] 

$ getent passwd foobar
foobar:x:1002:1002:foobar foobar,,,:/home/foobar:/bin/bash
```

As you can see in the 5th field the comments that i have not given any input are kept blank with commas `,` separating them.

**SECOND CASE:** All info are given:

```
$ sudo adduser foobar
Adding user `foobar' ...
Adding new group `foobar' (1002) ...

..........Truncated...............
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for foobar
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: foobar foobar
    Room Number []: 10
    Work Phone []: 1010
    Home Phone []: 1234
    Other []: spamegg
Is the information correct? [Y/n] 

$ getent passwd foobar
foobar:x:1002:1002:foobar foobar,10,1010,1234,spamegg:/home/foobar:/bin/bash
```

As you can see all parts of 5th field are now populated with the comma separated values given as input.

**CHANGING VALUE:** If you want to change the value of the comment field to something else you can use `usermod` command with `-c` (`--comment`) option:

```
$ sudo usermod -c "spamegg" foobar 

$ getent passwd foobar
foobar:x:1002:1002:spamegg:/home/foobar:/bin/bash
```

Or the better way as @muru suggested in the comment, use `chfn`. If you are logged on as the user `foobar` (in this example), then you can use just `chfn`, or as root `sudo chfn foobar`. It will prompt you for entering values one by one again, you can also change any individual value by using appropriate option of `chfn`. Check `man chfn` for details.

Comment: Use `chfn` instead of `usermod` for changing GECOS.

Comment: I didn't know what that commas meant. Then I will leave passwd file as it is... I will use @Terrance script to display Full name... Thanks

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva I have shown you why you are getting three comma "," in the 5th field.. See my examples closely..also check the way how the value can be changed..the command you're using will get you the Value back to understand the reason why this is happening and how to change the value check my answer..

Comment: I said "I did't know" not "I don't know". I guess "I didn't know" means that I in pass didn't know. but when you answered my question i learned that... Am I right? perhaps my native language isn't english, is portuguese. If i am incorrect please correct me...

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva No problem :)  note that if my answer solved your question please select the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Comment: ok, but you may want add @Terrance info... was useful for me

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva Well, thats an different issue i believe..i can also give you another way using `grep` to get the full name `getent passwd "$USER" | grep -Po "\d+:\d+:\K[^,:]*"` ....also note that you should use `getent` to parse the user/group conf files rather than parsing them directly..

Comment: I wonder what user name: "Mayl, Hee" and other: "Spam, Green Eggs & Ham" would show. Sister-site answer for comparison: https://superuser.com/questions/332804/why-are-there-weird-commas-in-my-etc-passwd-file